# Can function with same signature but different implementation be triggered simultaneously in python?

Tags: python, oop, factory-pattern

```
class A(Factory):
  def func1(self, param1):
    print(param1 + " class A")
  def func_A(self):
    print("Func A")

class B(Factory):
  def func1(self, param1):
    print(param1 + " class B")
  def func_B(self):
    print("Func B")

class Factory:
  @abstactmethod
  def func1(self, param1):
    pass


  f = Factory()
  f.func1(param1) # Expected Output: param1 ClassA param1 ClassB
```

How can I make the common interface ie. Factory to trigger both the common function in ClassA and ClassB simultaneously? I have been told that factory pattern may help, but I don't understand how to implement a factory pattern that triggers functions in both ClassA and ClassB with only a single invocation.

Comment: The `Factory` class has to be defined *before* its subclasses. You can't create instances of an abstract base class. The last two lines should not be indented. You misspelled `abstract`.

Comment: By simultaneously, do you mean launch 2 threads? As it stands, `Factory` knows nothing about its subclasses.

Comment: If you want an object that executes both functions, you need a class like: `class AB(A, B):`

Comment: @Axe319 Yes launch two threads at once.

Comment: @Barmar The only issue in this is I do not want to inherit the methods from class A and class B to the derived class AB. Is it possible to have a class AB without inheritance?

Comment: @Axe319 Not quite true - there would be `Factory.__subclasses__()` returning a list of `[A, B]` here.

Comment: If you want two objects that each run in their own thread, you need to call `A()` and `B()` to create them. You can create a factory function that creates them, that's not the same as a superclass.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to provide a new class that will (optionaly) inherit from both `A` and `B` and where `func1` calls the same method from both classes.

A trivial implementation could be:

```
class Both(A, B):
    def func1(self, param1):
        A.func1(self, param1)
        B.func1(self, param1)

f = Both()
f.func1('param')
```

it gives as expected:

```
param class A
param class B
```

Comment: I know this is the easiest one. However we want to have a design that invokes both the class functions with a single invocation.

Comment: If `A.func1` and `B.func1` both use `super`, then you get all relevant `func1` functions called in a chain automatically. (In fact, you don't even need to define `Both.func1`. `f.func1` invokes `A.func1` via inheritance, which invokes `B.func1` via `super`, which invokes `Factory.func1` via `super`. `Factory`, as the "owner" of `func1`, does *not* use `super`, in order to terminate the chain.)